# Unable to resolve module even it existed ReactNative

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I'm using React-native to develop a mobile app and got the below issue.

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module ../../globals/styles/appColor from .../src/containers/LoginScreen/style.ts: 

None of these files exist:
  * src/globals/styles/appColor(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * src/globals/styles/appColor/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  1 | import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
> 2 | import AppColor from "../../globals/styles/appColor";
```

This is my Code:

[image: styles.ts]
style.ts

[image: appColor.ts]
appColor.ts

I'm using `**RN 0.67.3**`

my code still work properly before, but now I'm getting this error,
I don't have any clue to solve this issue.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: i've just tried typing again import.... and i've passed above error but i need to do that again many times in many wheres that use import, i don't know real reason of this issue, anyone know about it?